# Is there an equivalent to vscode's quick open (ctrl+P) in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

One of my favorite features in vscode is hitting ctrl+P, start typing the name of the file I'm looking for, and then hit enter when it's the top suggestion to open it. It's super convenient.

I can't seem to find anything like it in JetBrains PyCharm.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: finds a class by name.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>: finds any file or directory by name (supports CamelCase and snake_case).

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/searching-everywhere.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Shift twice on MacOS.

Comment: @OscarVanL Double shift also works on Windows :)

Answer (score 4):

Try double shift. Works on Windows and Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

I found below commands are very helpful.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> : Recent files

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> : Recent locations

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode keymap in Rider so in my case it's Ctrl+P, but the default IntelliJ command is Ctrl+Shift+N, and the command is called "Go to File"

[image]
[image]